# Passing variable from controller to the master layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a main layout in views/layouts/main.blade.php
How do I pass a variable that is in my ListingsController.php

```
public function getMain() {
        $uname = Auth::user()->firstname;
        $this->layout->content = View::make('listings/main')->with('name', $uname);
 }
```

and then I add this to my main.blade.php that is in listings/main

```
@if(!Auth::check()) 
<h2>Hello, {{ $name }}</h2>
@endif
```

It works but I cannot pass that variable to the mmaster layout in views/layouts/main.blade.php 
I simply need to display user's firstname in the header.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should work the way it its, but...  If you need to spread something to more than one view, you better use `View::composer()` or `View::share()`:

```
View::share('name', Auth::user()->firstname);
```

If you need it only on your layout.main, you can:

```
View::composer('layouts.main', function($view)
{
    $view->with('name', Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->firstname : '');
});
```

If you need it on all your views you can:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('name', Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->firstname : '');
});
```

You can even create a file for this purpose, something like `app/composers.php` and load it in your `app/start/global.php`:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

Comment: I added the second snippet to my ListingsController's construct and it was available on all "Listing" pages but when I goto users/dashboard, I get an error "variable not found". I tried the second method to create a file and load it in global.php but that didn't work either, same error.

Comment: I added it to UsersController.php as well and now it is available on all users/* but I don't think that's practical.

Comment: It's not and it should work using composers globally. This is what I do for my views and it really works fine. Try to remove from the controller and use `View::composer('*', ...)` it must bound it to all your views.

Comment: This is my View now in listings __construct  

View::composer('*', function($view)  
        {  
            $view->with('name',  Auth::user()->firstname);  
        });  
  
But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I think it worked. I revisited composers.php that I just created, I had a typo in there. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should use service provider

Comment: You can also create a base controller which will be extended by other controllers and define stuff like this there. It will be available to all your controllers and views

Answer (score 2):

For this use a dedicated class.

First:

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('layouts.master', 'App\Http\Composers\MasterComposer');
}
```

And then:

```
// app/Http/Composers/MasterComposer.php
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class MasterComposer {

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('variable', 'myvariable');
    }
}
```

Remember to register service provider.

More: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->data['uname'] = 'some_username';
return View::make('dashboard.home', $this->data);
```

Edit::
example:

```
<?php 
class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
        protected $layout = 'layouts.front';

    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
               $this->data['sidewide_var'] = 'This will be shown on every page';
           $this->layout = View::make($this->layout, $this->data);
        }
    }

}
```

_

```
<?php 
class BlogController extends BaseController {
    public function getPost($id)
    {
      $this->data['title'] = 'Post title'; //this will exist on only this page, but can be used in layouts/front.blade.php (for example)
      return View::make('blog.single_post', $this->data);
    }
}
```

this is the way I am using controllers.
Both $sidewide_var and $title can be used in layout or view

Comment: Perhaps you can add a bit more information? Right now your post is quite confusing.